# URL call in PHP

Tags: php, http, web-services

I'm using an API in PHP.
I have to push datas into this API. For example, if I go to http://www.api.com/api.php?data=mydata , I push "mydata" to the API.

In fact I want to use PHP instead of typing that data in URL bar (that could be very nice haha)

Comment: It's totally unclear what you are trying to achieve & what you already tried..

Comment: Try to add this to before the first php code line: ```$_GET["data"] = "mydata";```. Please tell me if it works!

Comment: You could use [curl](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this do want you need?

```
$URL = "http://www.api.com/api.php?data=mydata";
$data = file_get_contents($URL);
```

data now contains the response.

Comment: I made the request on a wrong url, great Job Clément haha I always had 404 error. Now it's ok :-) thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

Did you try looking at cURL? http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

example:

```
$ch = curl_init();// init curl
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.api.com/api.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);// set post data to true
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"data=mydata&foo=bar");// post data

// receive server response ...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);// gives you a response from the server

$response = curl_exec ($ch);// response it ouputed in the response var

curl_close ($ch);// close curl connection
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to POST data ? Check out http_post_data :

http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-post-data.php

Comment: get is okay, it's the same for that app